# How to make an alias active in both current session and in .bashrc at same time?

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I just found frequently I decide to add an alias for longer time use at the same time use it now. So I have to type the same thing twice, first in current bash session then .bashrc.

Comment: First, put it in the `.bashrc`, then `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I have this at the top of my `~/.bash_aliases`: `alias realias='source ~/.bash_aliases'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define this function (say, in your `.bashrc`):

```
function permAlias {
    alias "$@"   # set the alias(es) in this session
    printf 'alias %q\n' "$@" >> ~/.bash_aliases  # set it for all sessions
}
```

Then use it the same way you would make a normal alias:

```
% permAlias foo='/path/to/command -some --options=here'
```

Note: This isn't the most robust solution in the universe.  It will probably break under all sorts of different use cases.  But it will work for simple things.

Comment: Your `.bash_aliases` will keep growing if you tweak or otherwise shadow existing aliases, but other than that, this is going to work well in typical situations (after a few quoting tweaks).

Comment: Works wonders most of time!

Answer (score 0):

I learned "the realias trick" from a talk by Damian Conway. The realias trick is documented at [Modern Perl Programming](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/10/remove-the-little-pessimizations.html). It follows the basic steps explained at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/, automating the final 'source'

Here is how I do it:

1. In `.bashrc`, ensure there is a line such as:

```
  source ~/.bash_aliases
```

or

```
  . ~/.bash_aliases
```

2. Ensure ~/.bash_aliases has a line like this:

```
  alias realias='$EDITOR ~/.bash_aliases; source ~/.bash_aliases'
```

3. Start a new shell to pick up the changes to .bashrc and .bash_aliases.
4. Run `realias`, which will start your editor on ~/.bash_aliases
5. Add your new alias or shell function. Eg:

```
  alias psme='ps -fu ${USER}'
```

6. Save and exit. On exit, the shell `source`s ~/.bash_aliases
7. Use your brand new alias.

```
$ psme
```

Because it is so convenient to add and use a new alias or shell function, my ~/.bash_aliases file has become a repository of anything slightly complicated that I expect to use again.